# How to add popover to an image in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, popover

I have an app in react native and I have a small image/icon that supposed to be as information icon. I looked all over the option I had found and didn't find anything that can help me and working for iOS and android.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={this.clickedInformationButton}>
          <ResponsiveImage
            style={styles.infoIcon}
            source={require('../assets/images/info-icon.png')}
            initWidth="20"
            initHeight="20"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

this is my image all I want to do is when I press on it I would like to get a small popover from this image with some text inside.

I have been looking for this all day and nothing came up, if you have any example, guide which can help me I would be thankful.

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample popover how would it look like, @Tal Shani ?

Comment: @Sateesh just added

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for, but take a look at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip

Comment: thank you for the answer... I just added an image for what im looking for, is your answer fit to my image?

Comment: Cant install it on iOS and android when I link it nothing happened and when I look for this library cant find the xcodeproj for the iOS

Comment: Yep , it looks like this module does what you are looking for, i am not the writer of this lib, for any issues you can contact them : https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-popover/issues

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

that [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popover-view) work for me well!